# What is the most efficient way of storing a list inside pandas column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, twitter

I have a pandas dataframe containing 100 million tweets.

I have extracted URL's from the data and have currently stored it as a list in pandas column:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DC3I.png)

I want to run analysis on these URL's (like sorting by domain name,finding out what type of user posted which domains).

Is it possible to store like this:
[Custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TLE0.png)

where the URL column is pandas series with dynamic size so i can easily process? Otherwise what would be the best way to store the urls for efficiency while applying pandas operations and speed?

Answer (score 0):

yes if you concat strings with `\n` like 'url1\nurl2\nurl3'

if you have list of url, you can use join:

```
listurl = ['url1','url2','url3']
print('\n'.join(listurl))
```